# Using Javascript to replace a href with onlick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change every anchor with class `.example-class` and change its href from

```
href="https://www.example.com/?fsaction=doSomething&id=123"
```

to

```
onClick="myFunction('id=123')"
```

Something along the lines of

```
$('.example-class').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var idOnly = (href -remove everything before and including id=);
  $(this).attr('onclick', "id='" + idOnly + "'")
  .removeAttr('href');
});
```

How can I "remove everything before and including id=" to get just `123` and will this work?

Comment: I don't think honestly it's a duplicate of that. I would reopen the question, or at least elaborated better why it was closed.

Comment: Do you want `onClick="myFunction('id=123')"` or `onClick="myFunction(123)"`

Comment: The former, as in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
$('.example-class').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var idOnly = (new URL(href)).searchParams.get("id");
  $(this).attr('onclick', "myFunction('id=" + idOnly + "')")
  .removeAttr('href');
});
function myFunction(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="example-class" href="https://www.example.com/?fsaction=doSomething&id=123">Here</a>
```

Comment: Fixed. I must've copied something bad or accidentally added something. After copying again, all is fine. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an alternative to changing the links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50850354/295783

Answer (score 0):

You can use `href.split('&')[1].split('=')[1]` to get the `id` value only:

```js
$('.example-class').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var idOnly = href.split('&')[1].split('=')[1];
  $(this).attr('onclick', "myFunction('"+idOnly+"')")
  .removeAttr('href');
});

function myFunction(id){
  console.log('id is ' + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class = 'example-class' href="https://www.example.com/?fsaction=doSomething&id=123">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers I would probably wrote something among this line, in vanilla javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.example-class").forEach(a => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(a.search);
  const id = params.get("id");
  a.removeAttribute("href");
  a.addEventListener("click", myFunction.bind(a, `id=${id}`));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to running over all links and change them:

```js
$('.example-class').on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var idOnly = (new URL(href)).searchParams.get("id"); // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837858/295783
  myFunction("id=" + idOnly);
});
function myFunction(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="example-class" href="https://www.example.com/?fsaction=doSomething&id=123">123</a><br/>
<a class="example-class" href="https://www.example.com/?fsaction=doSomething&id=456">456</a><br/>
```